# Merging several daraframes of different size in Python without losing columns

Tags: r, pandas, numpy, merge

I am analyzing the code of another person. Let me know what is the best way to share data for the reprex.

There are four dataframes

```
print('profile: ',list(clean_profile.columns))
print('portfolio: ',list(clean_portfolio.columns))
print('offer_data: ',list(offer_data.columns))
print('transaction: ',list(transaction_data.columns))
```

Output

```
profile:  ['gender', 'age', 'id', 'income', 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
portfolio:  ['reward', 'difficulty', 'duration', 'offerid', 'bogo', 'discount', 'informational', 'email', 'mobile', 'social', 'web']
offer_data:  ['customerid', 'event', 'value', 'days', 'offerid', 'completed', 'received', 'viewed']
transaction:  ['customerid', 'days', 'amount']
```

In total there are 32 columns in these dataframes (many variables are dummy).

Their shapes are different

```
(14613, 10) (10, 11) (146615, 8) (122176, 3)
```

Then a transformation occurs.

```
clean_data = []

# combining the data to construct meaning
customerid_list = offer_data['customerid'].unique()

for customerid in customerid_list:
# select profile of the customer
cur_customer = clean_profile[clean_profile['id']==customerid]

# select the associated offers of that customer
customer_offer_data = offer_data[offer_data['customerid']==customerid]
customer_offer_data = customer_offer_data.drop(columns='customerid')
customer_offer_data.reset_index(drop=True)

# select transaction associated to that customer
customer_transaction_data = transaction_data[transaction_data['customerid']==customerid]
customer_transaction_data = customer_transaction_data.drop(columns='customerid')
customer_transaction_data.reset_index(drop=True)

event_type=['completed','received','viewed','value']
offer_received = customer_offer_data[customer_offer_data['received']==1]
offer_received = offer_received.drop(columns=event_type).reset_index(drop=True)

offer_viewed = customer_offer_data[customer_offer_data['viewed']==1].drop(columns=event_type).reset_index(drop=True)

offer_completed = customer_offer_data[customer_offer_data['completed']==1].drop(columns=event_type).reset_index(drop=True)

rows=[]
for idx in range(offer_received.shape[0]):
    cur_offer_id = offer_received.iloc[idx]['offerid']
    cur_offer = clean_portfolio.loc[clean_portfolio['offerid']==cur_offer_id]
    days = cur_offer['duration'].values[0]
    cur_offer_startime = offer_received.iloc[idx]['days']
    cur_offer_endtime = offer_received.iloc[idx]['days'] + days
    
    # select the transactions which falls in the validity period
    select_transaction = np.logical_and(customer_transaction_data['days']>=cur_offer_startime,
                                       customer_transaction_data['days']<=cur_offer_endtime)
    # select the offers viewed which falls in the validity period
    select_offer_viewed = np.logical_and(offer_viewed['days']>=cur_offer_startime,
                                        offer_viewed['days']<=cur_offer_endtime)
    # select the offers completed which falls in the validity period
    select_offer_completed = np.logical_and(offer_completed['days']>=cur_offer_startime,
                                           offer_completed['days']<=cur_offer_endtime)
    
    # determine whether the curent offer was successful
    cur_offer_successful = select_offer_completed.sum() > 0 and select_offer_viewed.sum()>0
    cur_offer_transaction = customer_transaction_data[select_transaction]
    
    # collect the information in dictionary format
    cur_row={
        'offerid': cur_offer_id,
        'customerid': customerid,
        'time':cur_offer_startime,
        'offersuccessful':int(cur_offer_successful),
        'totalamount':cur_offer_transaction['amount'].sum()
    }
   
    cur_row.update(cur_offer.iloc[0,1:].to_dict())

    cur_row.update(cur_customer.iloc[0,1:].to_dict())

    rows.append(cur_row)
    clean_data.extend(rows)


    clean_data = pd.DataFrame(clean_data)
```

When I check columns, 9 columns are absent in my output

```
# Check columns
clean_data.columns

Index([        'offerid',      'customerid',            'time',
   'offersuccessful',     'totalamount',      'difficulty',
          'duration',            'bogo',        'discount',
     'informational',           'email',          'mobile',
            'social',             'web',             'age',
                'id',          'income',              2013,
                2014,              2015,              2016,
                2017,              2018],
  dtype='object')
```

The weirdest thing - my output is different from the person's output. For example, columns gender and reward disappeared while in the code of another person the column age is absent (for example).

Any idea how to merge 32 columns without losing all information?

Comment: why not do a left merge to the specific table you are interested in? or even a full/outer merge? No need of loops

Comment: How do you see it? In my initial data one df has 120K rows and another one is 10 rows. After merging they are the same.

Comment: that is a left merge

Comment: @Onyambu, sorry I am new to Python, how will it merge without keys with different sizes?

Comment: You must have keys. `profile.merge(offer_Data,left_on = "id", right_on = "customerid").merge(transaction_data, left_on="id", right_on = "customerid").merge(portfolio, on = "offerid")`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the output is not that what I expected. Maybe there are some problems with data.

Comment: I do not know exactly what you are merging on. You need to merge on specific items, probably including the transaction date etc, Sorry cannot help since there is no data here